# Regexp ignore whitespace in pattern

Tags: regex, scala

I'm used to writing regexp using pcre, since they cat get quite long I like the x modifier which lets me enter newlines and spaces without affecting the pattern, i.e. /123   456/x <=> /123456/

Is it possible to do the same in scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use inline `(?x)` modifier:

```
val pattern = new Regex("(?x)123 456")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/3OnVl7):

```
var str = "123456"
val pattern = new Regex("(?x)123 456")
val res = pattern.findAllIn(str).toArray
println(res.deep.mkString(", ")) 
// = > 123456
```